# PostgreSQL database - bloating - problem performance, storage, locking, dead tuples

Tags: postgresql

Can anyone tell me why someone can bloat your database tables when trying just one little thing in another session like this:

**session 1:**

```
select pg_sleep(1000000);
```

and you can try in another session something like this for test case you can take:

**session2:**
You can try UPDATE any table which you have to see.
or you can use

```
pgbench  -i -s 150
pgbench -c 10 -T 10 -j 10
```

And you will see a lot of dead_tuples which no one can erase if you don't kill session 1 !!!

```
 schemaname |     relname      | n_live_tup |n_dead_tup |last_autovacuum   
------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------------
 public     | pgbench_branches |         50 |    1087141| 2023-03-18 
 public     | pgbench_tellers  |        500 |    980411 | 2023-03-18 
 public     | pgbench_accounts |    5000000 |    980411 | 2023-03-18
```

when you try to

```
vacuum (verbose) pgbench_accounts;

INFO:  vacuuming "public.pgbench_accounts"
INFO:  table "pgbench_accounts": found 0 removable, 5980411 nonremovable row versions in 98115 out of 98115 pages
DETAIL:  **980411 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 169371**
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
CPU: user: 0.83 s, system: 0.03 s, elapsed: 0.87 s.
```

You will see that a txn with xmin 169371 in session 1 inflates the whole database!

I know I have to kill that session. I know when I have an active txn (MVCC - keeping old records) someone can just run in another session for example pg_sleep(1000000000) and go to sleep and your database will be bloated.

Does anyone know how to avoid this database behavior. I don't want some transaction that has nothing to do with the tables to bloats my entire database. Any idea?

Comment: If you are forced to allow the kinds of incompetents and/or psychopaths who would craft and execute such a scenario to write SQL against your database, then respond in kind by setting a statement timeout at the server:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#:~:text=statement_timeout%20(integer)

Comment: Give them their own replica to play with, so they don't bloat *your* database…

Comment: I am getting this error: `pgbench: pgbench: fatal: too many client connections for select()` ?

Comment: Mike: If I set statement_timeout, also I will kill my other active transaction. Bergi: I also know that I can give replica for playin. Luuk: That error which you get pgbench: pgbench: fatal: too many client connections for select() is because there was a big number for connect, use  pgbench -c 10 -T 10 -j 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting for that, [old_snapshot_threshold](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-ASYNC-BEHAVIOR)

It is, of course, not free of consequences.

Comment: Ok, this is very interesting, like UNDO segments in Oracle (snapshot too old). But this option will not be useful if you put at value of 1h or more. It is very interesting in Postgres that someone can influence the entire database in this simple way.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be useful to put at 1h or more?

Comment: If you have a database that updates a million rows in one minute, then if someone did an uncommitted transaction or pg_sleep, then all the tables would bloat within that hour.